# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: unix, gcc, gfortran, macos-mojave

I have tried many workarounds (brew upgrade/update, brew doctor, reinstalling gcc and gfortran, exporting libraries path etc.) to solve this issues, but none of them succeeded.
When I try to execute a Fortran executable I get the same error message:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/...
  Reason: image not found

I have read many different suggestions, is there a set of steps to follow to solve this problem?

Thank you.

More info:
MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

which gcc returns /usr/bin/gcc

which gfortran returns /usr/local/bin/gfortran

Comment: have you tried installing gfortran from here? http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-6.3-Sierra.dmg

Comment: It is also a good idea to build it from sources (take a look here) http://www.owsiak.org/running-open-mpi-on-macos/

Comment: I have tried with the .dmg installer, but I still get the same error message. I have also tried to build it from source, but I get several error messages in the Terminal (e.g. ../../gcc-5.1.0/gcc/graphite-poly.h:1092:19: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'isl_space_add_dims'
  isl_space *d2 = isl_space_add_dims (d1, isl_dim_in, n); )

Answer (score 13):

SOLVED!

You need first to locate the library:

```
locate libgfortran.3.dylib
```

You should get something like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@5/5.5.0_3/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

Then you can link the library to the right folder:

```
ln /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@5/5.5.0_3/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found a problem. I compiled a fortran file with

```
 9/libgfortran.5.dylib
```

I realised that in meanwhile, when I upgraded the homebrew, the updated version was

```
 10/libgfortran.5.dylib
```

Which was used when I executed the file. Repeated compilation solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force the version of gcc:

```
brew install gcc@5
```

I symbollically linked

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc\@5/5.5.0_6/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc\@5/5.5.0_6/bin/gfortran-5 /usr/local/bin/gfortran
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc\@5/5.5.0_6/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc\@5/5.5.0_6/lib/gcc/5/libquadmath.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
```