# Is it possible to install R in miniconda?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, package-managers, miniconda

I stumbled on this post:

Install of R in miniconda

https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-of-r-in-miniconda/19755

Is it possible to install R in miniconda?
As I understand it miniconda is a package manager for Python only according to this definition:

Miniconda

Miniconda is a free minimal installer for conda. It is a small, bootstrap version of Anaconda that includes only conda, Python, the packages they depend on, and a small number of other useful packages, including pip, zlib and a few others. Use the conda install command to install 720+ additional conda packages from the Anaconda repository.

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Or is it possible to use it with R?

I know Anaconda 3 offers R support.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the posts in the link you provided? It describes a direct methodology and suggested fix in case it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Try reading the comments to the link you provided in your question, within there they describe how to solve the problem.

Comment: Again you are not specific. If you refering to the link to the doc, this does not answer my question.  I knew I could install R in Anaconda full version like explained there. I did  not know I could install R with Miniconda. The right answer Miniconda is the command line tool for Conda and not only a package manager for Python. R can than be installed with Miniconda.
The definition of conda given here was irritating me:

Miniconda is a small, bootstrap version of Anaconda that includes only conda, Python.
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miniconda (the light, non-GUI version of Anaconda) gives you access to `conda` on the command line, and with that you can install R, along with some common packages, as follows:

```
conda install r r-essentials --channel conda-forge
```

And any further R packages you need:

```
conda install r-<package-name> --channel conda-forge
```

The "Conda" ecosystem is language-agnostic, it delivers whatever you ask for (if it exists in the repository) and installs the necessary platform binaries, but I would suggest creating a virtual environment specific to each "language platform", to ensure isolation.

Example:

```
conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base

conda activate r_env

conda list
```

And work within this environment to run R and install new packages.

To leave the virtual environment:

```
conda deactivate
```