# I am getting this error message: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: macos, gcc, linker-errors, gfortran, apple-m1

I am using the newest Macbook Air with M1 chip. I am trying to execute a file from a command line and I am receiving this error message

**dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libgfortran.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Volumes/JP_External/DOCK/dock6/bin/sphgen
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      sphgen -i INSPH -o OUTSPH**

I tried to reinstall gcc using homebrew packages and try to follow the solution from this ([dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib Reason: image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207357/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-gfortran-lib-libgfortran-3-dylib-reason-im))

When I tried to locate my gfortran, I get the following error message.

**WARNING: the locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:**

**sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist**

**Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to execute? Did you run the command you were suggested? What happened?

Comment: I tried to run the command, sphgen -i INSPH -o OUTSPH and the first bold phrase is the error message I got

Comment: How did you install gcc? Is it the ARM version?

Comment: I installed it using homebrew

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/k3huza/does_homebrew_gcc_work_on_the_m1_macs/

Comment: What does `gfortran -v` say? If anything at all.

Comment: Yeah, I read that thread before. I thought it might have been compatible by now but I guess it is still not upto date yet.

Comment: Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.1.0_1)

Comment: When I type where gcc, it gives me back /usr/bin/gcc. Since it is trying to load the library from this directory /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libgfortran.5.dylib, could that be the cause?

Comment: Yes, it could..